# Converting Cell values into Columns and flag the new cells

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame like this one:

| Location1 | Location2 | Location3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |

And I need to take the numbers and convert them to columns and flag the occurrences of the original cells

| Location1 | Location2 | Location3 | is_1 | is_2 | is_3 | is_4 | ... | is6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | ... | 0 |

What is the best way / operation to do this over the original df and create a new one with this structure ?

Answer (score 2):

You want `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.stack(), prefix='is').groupby(level=0).max())
```

Output:

```
   Location1  Location2  Location3  is_1  is_2  is_3  is_4  is_5  is_6
0          1          2          3     1     1     1     0     0     0
1          2          5          1     1     1     0     0     1     0
2          3          6          2     0     1     1     0     0     1
3          3          1          4     1     0     1     1     0     0
```